# applying mvn commands via intelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

How to run following mvn commands via intelliJ IDEA? I can run these commands from terminal but how to do the same in the IDE for the project opened in it?

```
--mvn clean dbmaintain:updateDatabase
--mvn clean package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to "Edit Configuration" and create a new "Maven Run/Debug Configuration". There you can define the command line and the working directory.

An other way of doing the same is : open de maven projects view (on right edge of the window) expend your module, expand the "Life-cycle", select the phase you need to run. Then a simple rigth click shows a popup allowing you to "run" the phase or create a run configuration preconfigured with the working dir and the phase. (you can always edit it)

Comment: thx. package commands create a WAR file, how to deploy it and run via same IDE?

Comment: see this this plugin http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide or this one http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin . Configure it in your pom and run the corresponding goal as explain in the post

Comment: IDEA supports deployment from the external source, check application server run/debug configuration, deployment tab, specify the maven artifact location you want to deploy.

Comment: No, Community Edition doesn't support application servers, see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html .